# Assumptions Need on a Measure Space to Guarantee the Existence of a Certain Set

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, measure-theory

First question: If $f : X \to [0,\infty]$ is a measurable function and $A$ and $B$ are disjoint measurable sets in $X$, then is it true that $$\int_{A \cup B} f \, d \mu = \int_A f \, d \mu + \int_B f \, d \mu?$$

Second question:Let $X$ be some space with $\sigma$-algebra $\frak{M}$ and measure $\mu : {\frak M} \to [0,\infty]$.  what are the assumptions on $X$ and $\frak{M}$ on it, minimal in number, such that there exists an $E \in \frak{M}$ with $0 < \mu(E),\mu(E^c) < \infty$?

Regarding the first, I didn't feel it justified its own post, since it is essentially a yes or no question (asked in chat but no responses). Regarding the second question, if we need to put conditions on $\mu$ that rule out trivial answers, please do so.

Comment: For the first question, yes. 
\begin{align*}
\int_{A \cup B} f d \mu = \int_{X} 1_{A \cup B} f d\mu = \int_{X} 1_A f + 1_B f  d\mu = \int_{X} 1_A f d\mu + \int_{X} 1_B f d\mu = \int_A f d\mu + \int_B f d\mu.
\end{align*} Disjointness was used for the second equality.

Comment: The condition that there exists E with $0<\mu (E),\mu (E^{c}<\infty$ is very simple and I don't think you can think of a simpler sufficient condition in general. You may be interested, however, in reading about non-atomic measures.